# Retrieving the email of Facebook account that posted a particular POST_ID

Tags: php, facebook, email, facebook-fql

I am trying to create an application in which when an user will share a link, an email will be sent to the email of the account from which the URL have been shared.

The concept is, when a URL will be shared, the response brings a post_id along with the response.

When I get the response, then I want to get the email id of the account which triggered the share.

Here's my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function get_fb_share()
{
    alert('hii');
    FB.ui(
   {
     method: 'feed',
     name: 'IGUTS Share',
     link: "<?php echo base_url();?>",
     picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
     caption: 'Reference Documentation',
     description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.',
     message: 'Facebook Dialogs are easy!'
   },
   function(response) {
     if (response && response.post_id) {
       alert('Post was published.');
       console.log(response);
       alert(JSON.stringify(response));
     } else {
       alert('Post was not published.');
     }
   }
 );
}
</script>
```

The response.post_id is the post_id of the share I did on my account. Now using this, how can I get the email ID of the Facebook account that shared the link?

Maybe this will need FQL?

Comment: _“how can i get the email ID of the facebook account that shared the link”_ – you can of course __not do that at all.__

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook API is based on permissions, where you can request different `scopes` from the user. `email` is such a scope, and is required for you to get the email address of a specific user. If you're not familiar with the Facebook API, you can read more about permissions [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0). This goes for both FQL and Graph API, of course.